# How to enable HTTP POST requests in IIS7?

Tags: php, http, iis, iis-7

I'm totally new to IIS7.  I get a 400 error when doing any POST request. However GET requests work fine.  I'm using PHP for processing but i assume that IIS is missing some configuration to allow POST

Comment: You are sending a malformed POST request to IIS7: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891#tocHeadRef

Comment: im basically sending "POST http://www.site.com/test.php?q=1&id=2&name=jim".  How would that be malformed?  GET works ok.

Comment: oh. do i have to POST in the header or something?

Comment: Check your request headers. Probably you are doing something wrong there.

Comment: When sending POST requests, data are passed as part of the request ( in the message body), not in the URL.

Answer (score 3):

By default IIS and PHP accept POST requests correctly, I'm assuming that your "POST" request is malformed in some way, meaning it isn't really running as an actual POST request. Check out this [KB Article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/c7d368f0-f175-4d58-b7a8-977e1d67bd07.mspx?mfr=true) on IIS 400 error.

Can you write the code here or your request you are running, so we can see more and may be better able to help.

Comment: It's not very clear but the op actually found their solution, they mentioned in their comments. I'm going to leave your answer here because yours is much more obvious.